# How to I make faces opaque on the inside?

Tags: faces

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but whenever I make progress on buildings and other such things I'm designing in Blender, the view changes itself so that whenever I look at an object from the inside, everything becomes invisible, but whenever I see it from the outside, it's opaque. This is so irritating. Does anybody know how I can fix this annoying problem? Look at these two images that demonstrate it. I've switched between solid and texture, and that still doesn't fix the problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSgYs.jpg)[image]

Comment: Do a search for "Backface Culling" and also "Flip Normals".

Comment: .....-----.....-----

Answer (score 1):

You can apply solidify modifier to the walls and give the thickness as required.

Answer (score 0):

Deactive Backface culling under Shading settings in Properties panel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want the wall be visible from both outside and inside? If yes, do what j.akshat suggested.

If you only want the wall be seen from inside, select those faces, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and in the tool window (in the left) tick the box that says **Inside**